# Can't get jQuery code to work in Wordpress, even trying noConflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, conflict

I have some html and css code in wordpress to make an image grid gallery, with pop up and slider. I've coded it myself due to not being able to find a plugin with wordpress to match the design I want.

I know this is working as I have a working copy on my computer locally in brackets.io. After trying and failing inserting the code in WordPRess I looked online to try and see if I could find a solution. I did wfind the jquery no conflict stuff but I am not sure if I am writing the jquery code right?

Here is the site in question with all the code in place (HTML and CSS to hide the content) - http://loknar.idwithin.xyz - below the jquery code I am writing. Its working on my desktop so I reckon I am writing the code wrong for the no conflict?

Thanks.

```
$j=jQuery.noConflict();


$j(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content").slice(0, 4).show();
  $("#loadMore").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".content:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();
    if($(".content:hidden").length == 0) {
      $("#loadMore").text("No Content").addClass("noContent");
    }
  });
```

Comment: My guess... Is that this is not the correct path.. you are trying to include a src like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://loknar.idwithin.xyz/wp-content/themes/oceanwphttp://loknar.idwithin.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/ss.js?ver=1.0.0"></script>`

Comment: you see how broken that is?

Comment: you are also not closing you document ready function - so you get a syntax error as well

Comment: When I fixed it in my browser, the load more button works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace every instance of `$` with `$j`. Otherwise you'll still get conflicts.

Comment: I've tried this and its still not working. Unless I am adding in the jQuery wrong? I am just using an insert headers and footers plugin, putting it in <script> Tags.

Comment: I just checked your website, it seems that your script is included twice. I'm not familiar enough with wordpress but that doesn't seem like it should be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery` instrad of `$`, it happended to me in the past and it worked that way. The no-conflict mode is not necessary.